# How to add future stallments when stallment column is filled?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm working with an expenses dataset in Power Query and I want to insert a command step to automatically create future installments when an expense with installment is inserted. For example:

| Date | Expense | Installment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | yyyyyyy |  |
| zzzz | wwwwwww | 2/3 |

To:

| Date | Expense | Installment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx | yyyyyyy |  |
| zzzz | wwwwwww | 2/3 |
| zzzz | wwwwwww | 3/3 |

Beware that the installment can start at 1 or any other number.

Any thoughts?

Didn't achive anything worth sharing at this point.

Comment: So anytime something says X/Y in Installment column, you want to fill in all the other X's?

Comment: Exactly! Forgot to say that the date should go up by a month as well.

Comment: Expense is a number or a unique identifier?

Comment: String identifier, but not unique.

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this which creates all subsequent x/y combinations then filters out duplicates

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Expense"}, {{"data", each 
    let start=_,
    Prefix =Text.BeforeDelimiter(start[Installment]{0},"/"),  
    Suffix=Text.AfterDelimiter(start[Installment]{0},"/"), 
    InstallmentList=try List.Transform({Number.From(Prefix)..Number.From(Suffix)}, each Text.From(_)&"/"&Text.From(Suffix)) otherwise {},
    ExpenseList=List.Repeat({start[Expense]{0}},List.Count(InstallmentList)),
    DateList = try List.Generate(()=>[x=start[Date]{0},i=0], each [i]<List.Count(InstallmentList), each [i=[i]+1,x=Date.AddMonths([x],1)], each [x]) otherwise {}, //generate list of dates one month apart from each other
    NewTable=start & Table.FromColumns({DateList}&{ExpenseList}&{InstallmentList},{"Date","Expense","Installment"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(NewTable)
    in #"Removed Duplicates"
, type table [Date=nullable date, Expense=text, Installment=nullable text]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Installment"}, {"Date", "Installment"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to accept the solution